# Programatically assigning multiple user role ?

Tags: users

I am trying to assign multiple role while creating a user programatically. I am successfully creating a user and assigning one role using below code

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
// Mandatory.
$user->setPassword('111');
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail('abcd@gmail.com');
$user->setUsername('abcd');
$user->addRole('lecturer');
$user->save();
```

I want to assign two roles during this code execution and tried the below code but it did not work

```
$user->addRole(['lecturer','program coodinator']);
```

How do I assign this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [User::addRole](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AaddRole/8.2.x) it says

> `User::addRole($rid)`
>
> **string $rid**: The role ID to add.

Therefore, this cannot be an array. Thus, you must do this separate

```
$user->addRole('lecturer');
$user->addRole('program coodinator');
$user->save();
```

If you look at [class User](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8.2.x), there is no such thing as "addRoles" or any method that allows multiple way of doing it with an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the roles you are adding aren't already added to the user account, you can use the following code.

```
$roles = $user->getRoles(TRUE);
$user->set('roles', $roles + ['lecturer','program coodinator'])->save();
```

Since you are creating a user account, this code is probably sufficient. The more generic code would be the following one.

```
$roles = $user->getRoles(TRUE);
$user->set('roles', array_unique($roles + ['lecturer','program coodinator']))->save();
```

That code is similar to the code used by [`User::addRole()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AaddRole/8.6.x), with the exception it doesn't check the role being added is the *anonymous user* or the *authenticated* role.